# c++ - struct isn't recognized when using in a header file

Tags: c++, struct

I have a file named: `FeedbackCircuitVariables.h` with the following inside:

```
#pragma once

struct FeedbackCircuitVariables {
    // Unknown values (the ones which will be calculated).
    float m_Ic, m_Ib;
    float m_Vce;

    // Known values (the ones asked to user through keyboard).
    float m_Rc, m_Rb, m_Re;
    float m_Vbe, m_Vcc;
};
```

And a class in `FeedbackCircuit.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include "FeedbackCircuitVariables.h"

class FeedbackCircuit {
private:
    FeedbackCircuitVariables *m_pVariables;
public:
    FeedbackCircuit(const FeedbackCircuitVariables *variables);
};
```

And this is the definition of that class:

```
#include "FeeedbackCircuit.h"

FeedbackCircuit(const FeedbackCircuitVariables *variables) {

}
```

But inside the header of the class the compiler says that FeedbackCircuitVariables isn't a type name.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it the *compiler* or the *editor* that tells you there a problem?

Comment: Well, I guess actually the editor.

Comment: Write the constructor as `FeedbackCircuit::FeedbackCircuit(const FeedbackCircuitVariables *variables) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Unrelated: Is there a  reason you have separated FeedbackCircuitVariables.h and FeedbackCircuit.h? The naming suggests a tight relationship and the files don't appear to be particularly large

Comment: @user4581301 failed pImpl idiom. See GotW #100 & #101.

Comment: Below is my answer. It is also correct. If you don’t mind, please give it a check mark too!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your constructor syntax is wrong.

Change:

```
   FeedbackCircuit(const FeedbackCircuitVariables *variables)
```

To:

```
   FeedbackCircuit::FeedbackCircuit(const FeedbackCircuitVariables *variables)
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This is the scope of the thing you're defining.
```

Your code should build then.

Comment: Damnit, I'm an idiot. How did I not notice that? Thanks.

Comment: @RottenCheese if you accept any answer, it will let the community know that you are no longer seeking help here.

Comment: Done. I was waiting for the 10 minutes or so in order to be able to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the scope of `FeedbackCircuit(const FeedbackCircuitVariables *variables)` in `FeedbackCircuit.cpp`:

```
FeedbackCircuit::FeedbackCircuit(const FeedbackCircuitVariables *variables) {

}
```

Add `FeedbackCircuit::` to tell the editor and compiler where the function is located.